# SwipeRefresh layout not working in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, swiperefreshlayout

I am using swipe refresh layout to load datas from local sqlite i have set the limit 2 and offset as 0 when the list is refreshed the datas are not getting refreshed i don't know why it is not working can anyone help me reagrding this.

Database:

```
 public ArrayList<TransactionSum> getAllTransactionList(int offset) {

    ArrayList<TransactionSum> transactionsum = new ArrayList<TransactionSum>();
    String selectquery = "SELECT tid,SUM(totalamount) as 'total',strftime('%m-%Y', tdate) as 'month' FROM " + TRANSACTION_LABELS + " WHERE tdate BETWEEN (select min(tdate) from transactionlabel) AND (select max(tdate) from transactionlabel) GROUP BY strftime('%m-%Y', tdate) ORDER BY strftime('%m-%Y', tdate) DESC LIMIT "+2+" OFFSET "+offset+" ";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            TransactionSum transactiontotal = new TransactionSum();
            transactiontotal.setId(cursor.getString(0));
            transactiontotal.setTotalamount(cursor.getString(1));
            transactiontotal.setMonth(cursor.getString(2));

            transactionsum.add(transactiontotal);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return transactionsum;
}
```

Activity:

```
 @Override
public void onRefresh() {
    fetchList();
}

private void fetchList() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);


   databaseHandlerOtherChgs=new DatabaseHandlerOtherChgs(getApplicationContext());



    transactionitems=new ArrayList<TransactionSum>();
    transactionitems=databaseHandlerOtherChgs.getAllTransactionList(offSet);

       adapter = new TransactionListNewAdapter(this, transactionitems);
      for(int i=offSet;i<transactionitems.size();i++){
          offSet=offSet+i;
      }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: I think there is typo error in your Sqlite query, Change "+2+" to "+"2"+"

Comment: Ok but how do i refresh the list with new set of datas in it

Comment: Try to set offset 0 when refresh list.

Comment: sir have u worked in folding cell animation.I have tired it first as it was given it works fine.But when i added a list view inside the content layout.The cell gets expanded but it is not collapsed

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a whole new adapter every time you fetch the refresh the list, but you never do anything with this adapter. You have to set it on the view (`ListView`, `RecyclerView', whichever you are using).

Or, you could add a method to `TransactionListAdapter` that allows you to change the data in it, and use this method instead of creating new adapters all the time.

```
public void setTransactionList(ArrayList<TransactionSum> newList) {
    mList = newList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: but where i have to use this piece of code either in my adapter class or in my activity or in the database

Comment: @RameshR Whenever you load a new list. You need to give the adapter the new list, or else how can it show those items? (Or, you need to give `ListView` the new adapter you created, otherwise how can it show those items?)

Comment: how do i increement the offset when it is swiped as well as how could i found the total no of records in that table

Comment: @RameshR there's not enough information in your question about how your data is structured, etc. for someone else to create logic for you. You asked why list wasn't refreshed, and it's because your `ListView` needs the right adapter with the right data. If you have more questions about other aspects of this problem, start a new question instead of compounding them into this one.